# 3 linkbuttons one event handler

Tags: asp.net, linkbutton

I am a beginner in asp.net, I've done my research but not very clear.

I have 3 links lkn1,2,3

Basically, I am looking at something like this:

```
protected void lnkBtn_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
  LinkButton lnkRes = sender as LinkButton;
  string text = lnkRes.Text.Trim();
  string sql = ""
  if(text.ToUpper() == "INBOX")
  {
     sql = "SELECT * FROM InboxTbl where receiver_id = "helloworld";
  }
  else if(text.ToUpper() == "DRAFT")
  {
     sql = "SELECT * FROM Inbox where sender_id="HelloWorld";
  }
  else if(text.ToUpper() == "SENT")
  {
     sql = "SELECT * FROM Inbox where sender_id="HelloWorld";
  }
  if(sql != "")
  {
      SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(sql,ConnectionString);
      DataSet ds = new DataSet();
      adp.Fill(ds,"tbl");
      GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["tbl"].DefaultView;
      GridView1.DataBind();
  }
}
```

How do I write this code and where should I write it, so that depending on the text of the linkbutton, the respective sql statement is executed?

If this has anything to do with event handling.. 3links one event.. pls send me some links I could read and understand

Comment: What you've got here (barring some syntax errors) is basically correct. If you wire up your buttons to this one event handler it should work. Code it up, fix the syntax errors and then step through on the debugger to make sure that it's doing what you expect.

Comment: pay attention to your sql statements: select * is considered bad practice, better name each column you need. when using select * you will shoot your self in the foot when a column is added, renamed, moved position, deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w2tb12s%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is a link describing add event handlers. With event handling, when a certain action occurs, the response is to call a certain function (in our case `lnkBtn_Click`). For 3 different LinkButtons to use the same function, we just put the same function on the OnClick attribute - this is what makes the event handler for all three LinkButtons the same function.

Answer (score 1):

in the HTML write the below

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="lnk1" text="INBOX" OnClick="lnkBtn_Click" />
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="lnk2" text="DRAFT" OnClick="lnkBtn_Click" />
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="lnk3" text="SENT" OnClick="lnkBtn_Click" />
```

Comment: just writing this is the markup is sufficient ... i don't think so

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the text property use the source to find which button is clicked. Rest all looks fine to me.